# Objective C double assignment error

Tags: objective-c, double, precision

Is it normal for this line:
self->_latitude = 42.639914;

to produce this result during run-time immediately after the assignment?
_latitude   double  42.639913999999997

I'm confused. I thought floating point precision errors occur only when calculating stuff. Why create a different value on assignment?

Comment: Where's the "error"? 42.639913999999997 _is_ 42.639914.

Comment: What you are seeing is an artifact of the display method format precision.

Comment: Matt this is a rounding error obviously, the numbers are not the same. Patricia gave a very good answer. I just remembered reading a blog post a while back. It talked about "a problem you didn't know you have" and it was about slaying dragons and displaying floating point numbers on screen which, apparently, are equally difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Conversion of a decimal fraction to a binary floating point number **is** a non-trivial calculation that can require rounding.

The closest 64-bit binary IEEE 754 number to 42.639914 to is 42.63991399999999742931322543881833553314208984375, so rounding is required in this case.

The output was also rounded. If you look only at the input and rounded output, you have no way of knowing how much rounding error you got on conversion from decimal to binary floating point, and how much on the output conversion. The exact value above is the value that will be input to subsequent calculations.

You can explore this yourself using either a function that does exact conversion to decimal, or a web converter such as the Exploring Binary [Decimal to Floating-Point converter](http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/).

Comment: The maximum digits of precision for a 64-bit double is 16. The exams;e has 48 digits of precision, that is an incorrect representation. That a print method will produce 48 digits does not change that, do not ask for more precision than a double holds. See [IEEE floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Basic_and_interchange_formats).

Comment: @zaph Every finite double number does have an exact numerical value that can always be represented as a decimal fraction. In the link you referenced, look under "Formats" for the formula for calculating the numerical value. Often, it takes a surprising number of decimal digits. Digits beyond about 16 typically represent rounding error, because 53 binary digits are equivalent to about 15.9 decimal digits. However, when studying rounding error it really does help to look at, and think about, the exact values.

Comment: Past the 15.9 decimal digits (actually 15 to 17), the 53 bits, the digits are fantasy, they do not exist, displaying them is a lie.

Comment: @zaph You are, of course, free to choose whatever model works for you. I prefer the model in which every finite floating point number has a numeric value that can be calculated by the formula in the standard for two reasons. It is is compatible with the standard, and it allows reasoning about rounding error in ways that are just not possible in your model. See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#1127)

Comment: It is math and bits to represent doubles that dictate the precision, not what one want's to believe. Pi to 38 decimal places: The real [Pi](http://www.math.com/tables/constants/pi.htm) : 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375

As a double: `double pi = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375;`
        `NSLog(@"pi: %0.48f", pi);` : 3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875

After the 15th decimal digit the double version is no longer is correct, there are not the bits to represent it to more precision.

Comment: @zaph Precision is highly relevant to conversion of decimal fractions to double. Conversion the other way can be done without rounding for any finite double number. You had to use that fact in your comment - reasoning about rounding error needs to use the numeric value of the doubles involved, not just the most significant 16 digits.

Comment: Pixie dust, that must be it because the bits just aren't there.

Comment: @zaph Yes, from the point of view of Pi, 3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875 only represents it to 16 (not 15) digits. But that value does exist -- it is the exact representation of the double-precision number closest to Pi. The danger in calling the 'extra' digits "fantasy" is that it makes it sound like they are random or made up. Printing those digits is useful when you are trying to understand decimal/floating-point conversions.

Comment: @zaph But the bits *are* there. In binary, that value is 11.001001000011111101101010100010001000010110100011. You get one decimal digit for each bit to the right of the point.

Comment: @RickRegan Wow, how wrong! You do not get one decimal digit per binary bit,  you get one decimal digit (0-9) per ~3.3 binary bits (0-1). Best study [IEEE floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Basic_and_interchange_formats) which shows "binary64 Double precision Decimal digits15.95. Note that a binary bit holds 2 states, a decimal digit holds 10 states. It is impossible to map a binary bit's 2 states to a decimal digit's 10 states.

Comment: @zaph A binary fraction of n digits after the point will convert to a decimal fraction with n digits after the point. 0.10111 is 0.71875, 0.1000011100001 is 0.5274658203125, 0.000000000000000000000001 is 0.000000059604644775390625, etc.

Comment: Show the binary representation for 0.71874 that is different than the the binary representation for 0.71875 in the same number of bits. You have added significance and that is not allowed in math in this universe.

Comment: @zaph 0.71874 converts to 0.10110111111111110101100000111010010100111011100011101 which is 0.71874000000000004551026222543441690504550933837890625. Rounded to 17 digits that's 0.71874000000000005. It is different than 0.71875. In any case I think the point you are trying to make is that beyond a certain point the digits don't matter for decimal to floating-point conversion -- you'll get the same floating-point number. Of course. But we are talking about the reverse direction. We are not attributing significance to those decimal digits (in the sense you are talking) but they are there.

Comment: @zaph You keep appealing to "math" as an authority. Please give references to the relevant definitions and theorems. Don't worry about getting too technical - my bachelor's degree was in mathematics. Note that your assertions contradict the IEEE 754 specification, whose writers included mathematicians specializing in the topic.